# dotnet restore with update in the new csproj/msbuild-based projects?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-code, .net-core

How do I actually update the new csproj-based project's Nuget packages to the latest ones when using Visual Studio Code?

This is what I have within the .csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.0.0" />
```

If I do `dotnet restore` it will only install the specified package versions.

There is no `dotnet restore update` or `dotnet nuget update` option available.

All of the above referenced `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages have newer versions (1.1.0).

I would like to update the packages and have the references updated automatically in the same way we do this in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, VS Code does not have a built-in Nuget Manager tool. The only possible way is to edit `.csproj` file manually and update versions.

If regarding VS Code extensions,  there is a [Net Core Project Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ksubedi.net-core-project-manager) extension, that works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, that's also the response I got at .NET Core CLI's GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5425#issuecomment-274343316